# Apache Spark Server installation requires Hadoop? Not automatically installed?

Tags: apache-spark

I have my dev environment on my Mac. I have a dev Spark server on a freshly installed physical Ubuntu box.

In my code, running on the Mac, I have:

```
1   SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myapp").setMaster("spark://10.0.100.120:7077");
2   JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
3   javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN");
4   SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);
5
6   // Restaurant Data
7   df = sqlContext.read().option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd").json(source.getLocalStorage());
```

1) Clarification question: This code runs on my mac, connects to the server, but line #7 assumes the file is on my mac, not on the server, right?

2) On line 7, I get an exception:

```
16-07-10 22:20:04:143 DEBUG  - address: jgp-MacBook-Air.local/10.0.100.100 isLoopbackAddress: false, with host 10.0.100.100 jgp-MacBook-Air.local
16-07-10 22:20:04:240 INFO org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation - Listing file:/Users/jgp/Documents/Data/restaurants-data.json on driver
16-07-10 22:20:04:288 DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell - Failed to detect a valid hadoop home directory
java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.checkHadoopHome(Shell.java:225)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:250)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:447)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$json$JSONRelation$$createBaseRdd(JSONRelation.scala:98)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JSONRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(JSONRelation.scala:115)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.json.JSONRelation$$anonfun$4.apply(JSONRelation.scala:109)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
```

Do I have to install HADOOP on the server? - I imagine that from:

```
java.io.IOException: HADOOP_HOME or hadoop.home.dir are not set.
```

Comment: Which version of Spark did you download ? Usually Spark comes bundled with Hadoop but you might have downloaded one without it.

Comment: I actually download the bundled one, and went through the installation, but I did not have any Hadoop installed before.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really old question and things have changed a bit, so here are t2o ways:

1. Download (or clone) and run a super basic example from https://github.com/jgperrin/net.jgp.books.spark.ch01.
2. Use `brew` as in:

   ```
   brew install apache-spark
   ```