# Remote job on Apache Spark (Java)

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have set a new standalone Apache Spark server on a freshly installed Ubuntu server. I try to send my first job there and I am not very successful.

Here is what I do locally:

```
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstJob").setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext javaSparkContext = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    javaSparkContext.setLogLevel("WARN");
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(javaSparkContext);

    System.out.println("Hello, Remote Spark v." + javaSparkContext.version());

    DataFrame df;
    df = sqlContext.read().option("dateFormat", "yyyy-mm-dd")
            .json("./src/main/resources/north-carolina-school-performance-data.json");
    df = df.withColumn("district", df.col("fields.district"));
    df = df.groupBy("district").count().orderBy(df.col("district"));
    df.show(150);
```

It works: it displays the name of the school districts in NC with the number of schools in the district:

```
Hello, Remote Spark v.1.6.1
+--------------------+-----+
|            district|count|
+--------------------+-----+
|Alamance-Burlingt...|   34|
|Alexander County ...|   10|
|Alleghany County ...|    4|
|Anson County Schools|   10|
| Ashe County Schools|    5|
|Asheboro City Sch...|    8|
...
```

Now, if I change the first line to:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("myFirstJob").setMaster("spark://10.0.100.120:7077");
```

It goes well to:

```
Hello, Remote Spark v.1.6.1
16/07/12 10:58:34 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
16/07/12 10:58:49 WARN TaskSchedulerImpl: Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

The first thing which is strange (for me) is that the server has Spark 1.6.2. I was kind of expecting to see 1.6.2 as the version number.

Then on the UI, I go there and see:

[image: Spark UI]

If I click on app-20160712105816-0011, I get:

[image: Detail of app]

Any click on other link will bring me to my local Apache Spark instance.

After clicking around, I can see something like:

[image: App on the client]

And if I look at the log on the server I see:

```
16/07/12 10:37:00 INFO Master: Registered app myFirstJob with ID app-20160712103700-0009
16/07/12 10:37:03 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20160712103700-0009
16/07/12 10:37:03 INFO Master: Removing app app-20160712103700-0009
16/07/12 10:37:03 INFO Master: 10.0.100.100:54396 got disassociated, removing it.
16/07/12 10:37:03 INFO Master: 10.0.100.100:54392 got disassociated, removing it.
16/07/12 10:50:44 INFO Master: Registering app myFirstJob
16/07/12 10:50:44 INFO Master: Registered app myFirstJob with ID app-20160712105044-0010
16/07/12 10:51:20 INFO Master: Received unregister request from application app-20160712105044-0010
16/07/12 10:51:20 INFO Master: Removing app app-20160712105044-0010
16/07/12 10:51:20 INFO Master: 10.0.100.100:54682 got disassociated, removing it.
16/07/12 10:51:20 INFO Master: 10.0.100.100:54680 got disassociated, removing it.
16/07/12 10:58:16 INFO Master: Registering app myFirstJob
16/07/12 10:58:16 INFO Master: Registered app myFirstJob with ID app-20160712105816-0011
```

Which all seems ok to me...

I had a previous question (unresolved) at [Apache Spark Server installation requires Hadoop? Not automatically installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38298372/apache-spark-server-installation-requires-hadoop-not-automatically-installed), with the same environment, but this is a completely different - much smaller - app.

Any clue on what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Web UI screenshot, your server has no worker(slave). Spark provides a few script to start the cluster.

- sbin/start-all.sh : Start the master and the workers specified in the `conf/slaves`
- sbin/start-slaves.sh : Start only the slaves in `conf/slaves`
- sbin/start-master.sh : Start the master in the current machine
- sbin/start-slave.sh: Start slave in the current machine

If your cluster is configured correctly, then you only need to call `start-all.sh` on the master machine to start everything.

Comment: Thanks - that would make sense, I just need to understand how I create a config where I have the master and the slave on the same server. There is probably something I missed in http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/spark-standalone.html.

Comment: If you have the master and the slave on the same machine, just put the machine IP address in `conf/slaves`.

Comment: It works - I have another issue now, but this part works -- tx! I think I was on a more modern of slavery: you are a master, but when there are no slave, you do the job yourself...